# looking a way to extract pattern from a text file in linux

Tags: substring, design-patterns

I am using linux and bash. I have a text file with the context generated in run time by other program. The length, number of lines and content of the text file changed from time to time. But there is some pattern unchanged in the text, one typical example is

123098230984LD#2e3
123098230984LD#23234
XER_3424324_23424
   33: 34: 35: node:9-72-1408 &82 &34
$1231313
*3435322
link to port:323
3424242424LD#2234
332424LD#23424234

Here, I want to extract the pattern "node:NUMBER-NUMBER-NUMBER" and "port:NUMBER" but where it occurs in the text varied from time to time too. Now I manually extract the information. I am wondering if there is any way to extract the information automatically. What make it really difficult is the content change every time when the file generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to extract the desired fields by getting rid of the undesired bits:

```
pax> echo 'junk node:9-72-1408 more junk port:323 last junk'
     | sed -E 's/^.*(node:[0-9]+-[0-9]*-[0-9]*).*(port:[0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/'
node:9-72-1408 port:323
```

The `.*` bits simply represent any junk and the parentheses are used to "capture" the matching text so it can be used in the replacement (as `\1` and `\2`).

---

**Sidebar:**

If your version of `sed` doesn't support `-E` for extended regexes, it may support `-r`, as with certain versions of GNU `sed`.

Otherwise, you'll need to escape the parentheses and `+` characters:

```
pax> echo 'junk node:9-72-1408 more junk port:323 last junk'
     | sed  's/^.*\(node:[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\).*\(port:[0-9]\+\).*$/\1 \2/'
node:9-72-1408 port:323
```

The source code for GNU sed contains this little snippet:

```
/* Undocumented, for compatibility with BSD sed.  */
    case 'E':
    case 'r':
```

but this appears to have been introduced in 4.2 (i.e., it's in 4.2 but not in 4.1.5, the last of the 4.1 series). See [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/) for details.

---

And, if you need the actual values in variables, you can use something like:

```
pax> inpstr='junk-here node:9-72-1408 more-junk port:323 last-junk'

pax> node=$(echo "$inpstr" | sed -E 's/^.*node:([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+).*$/\1/')

pax> port=$(echo "$inpstr" | sed -E 's/^.*port:([0-9]+).*$/\1/')

pax> echo $inpstr
junk-here node:9-72-1408 more-junk port:323 last-junk

pax> echo $node
9-72-1408

pax> echo $port
323
```

(taking into account the earlier comments about using `-r` or adding extra escaping for "lesser" `sed` implementations).

Comment: thanks. I tried the command but it seems doesn't work in my system. I don't know why, there is no -E option in sed and the version for sed in my system is GNU sed version 4.1.5. I try man sed, it only have -e or -expression, I tried that also, but it doesn't give me the expected outcome. It shows "sed: -e expression #1, char 57: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS"

Comment: @user1285419, try using `-r` for extended regexes rather than the `-E`. `-E` works on my GNUsed4.2.1 even though it's not in the manpage. Otherwise, you'll have to slightly modify the regexes. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @user1285419: further on that, the `-E` switch was added to the 4.2 release which explains why your 4.1.x doesn't have it. However, since 4.1.0 has `-r`, you can just use that instead.